# Vagrantfile how to check if installed and install eventually?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I need to provide a self contained vagrantfile that checks (on reload or creation) if some piece of software is already installed and install it when its not. I'm not sure how to approach or write down that in the vagrantfile is there one simple line that could accomplish that? If not, whats the other relatively simple approach with configuration management tools like puppet or chef? In general what approach is the most effective/simple

Answer (score 0):

Use a [shell provisioner](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html)(for example in a debian base box):

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
   config.vm.provision 'foo', 
     type:  :shell, 
     inline: 'which foo &> /dev/null || apt-get install foo' 
end
```

This is idempotent because on the first time `which` will return `false` therefore `foo` will be install, but any other time(as long as the instance isn't destroyed) `which` will return `true` and nothing will happen.

The provisioner name `foo` can be use with the [`--provision-with`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/provision.html#provision-with-x-y-z) option:

```
vagrant provision --provision-with foo
```

*Note: This option can also be used with vagrant commands `up` and `reload`.*